# Is LLVM IR a graph?

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

I'm starting new research in the field of compiler optimization.
As a start, I'm looking into several different papers related and encountered a few different optimization techniques.

One main thing I'm currently looking at is the compilers' technique that converting input source code into a graph (e.g. control-flow, data-flow, linked list, etc.), then performs optimization onto the graph and produces the machine code. Code-to-Graph-to-Code. For example, JIT compilers in the JavaScript engines, i.e. V8, ChakraCore, etc.

Then, I came across LLVM IR. Because of the earlier searches, my impression of optimization on code is doing on a graph like explained above. However, I do not believe that is the case for LLVM, but I'm not sure. I found that there are tools to generate a control-flow graph from the LLVM IR, but it doesn't mean it's optimizing the graph.

So, my question is "Is LLVM IR a graph?" If not, how does it optimize the code? Code-to-Code directly?

Comment: See [this](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1603)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LLVM IR (and it's backend form, Machine IR) is a traditional [three-address code IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code) so technically is not a graph IR in the sense e.g. [sea-of-nodes IR](https://darksi.de/d.sea-of-nodes/) is. But it contains several graph structures in it: a graph of basic blocks ([Control Flow Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph)) and a graph of data dependencies (SSA [def-use chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use-define_chain)) which are used to simplify optimizations. In addition, during instruction selection phase in backend original LLVM IR is temporarily converted to a true graph IR - [SelectionDAG](https://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#introduction-to-selectiondags).

Comment: Excellent answer. There's only one thing to add: How code is optimised is a question for each pass. LLVM doesn't answer that in general, but rather leaves it to each pass. Most passes use a combination of the input code and one or more supporting data structures, which they may build themselves, [get from an "analysis pass"](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Pass.html#a4863e5e463fb79955269fbf7fbf52b80) or from the frontend if the pass is specific to a particular frontend.

Comment: @arnt thank you for the clarification! Feel free to merge it into this answer or add a new one (so that it can be +1'ed).

Comment: Thanks for the ‘sea of nodes’ reference — exactly what I’d been trying to find.